# Complete the program to display the following 3 lines

Tags: php

I need help with This problems...  Complete the program to display the following 3 lines

```
In the constructor of the abstract class
In the constructor of the class
the variable $value is: Jean Lafortune;
```

and here is the program:

```
<?php
/*  
    Complétez le programme pour qu'il affiche les 3 lignes suivantes 

    Dans le constructeur de la classe abstraite 
    Dans le constructeur de la classe 
    la valeur de $variable est : Jean Lafortune;
*/

/ *
    Complete the program to display the following 3 lines

    In the constructor of the abstract class
    In the constructor of the class
    the variable $ value is: Jean Lafortune;
* /
    abstract class classe_abstraite {
        private $variable = "";

        protected function __construct() {
            print "Dans le constructeur de la classe abstraite <br />";
        }

        abstract protected function set_variable($valeur) ;
        abstract protected function get_variable() ;
    }

    class Une_classe extends classe_abstraite {
        public function __construct() {
            print "Dans le constructeur de la classe <br />";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $o = new Une_classe;
    $o->set_variable("Jean Lafortune");
    print 'la valeur de $variable est : ' . $o->get_variable();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint in the error

```
PHP Fatal error: Class Une_classe contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (classe_abstraite::set_variable, classe_abstraite::get_variable)


abstract class classe_abstraite {
    private $variable = "";

    protected function __construct() {
        print "Dans le constructeur de la classe abstraite <br />";
    }

    abstract protected function set_variable($valeur) ;
    abstract protected function get_variable() ;
}

class Une_classe extends classe_abstraite {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print "Dans le constructeur de la classe <br />";
    }

    public function set_variable($valeur){ $this->variable=$valeur; }
    public function get_variable(){ return $this->variable; }
}

$o = new Une_classe;
$o->set_variable("Jean Lafortune");
print 'la valeur de $variable est : ' . $o->get_variable();
```

This returns:-

```
Dans le constructeur de la classe abstraite
Dans le constructeur de la classe
la valeur de $variable est : Jean Lafortune
```

Comment: This is more a comment rather than an actual answer!